# How to Find data already exist for nest js inside array

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, nest

I want to check the data is already exist in my database or not>
Following the code:

```
Entity
  @Column('simple-array')
  users: string[];
```

The following data in my database as

```
{
    id: '57b41c65-ae8d-4cf0-8246-a85f296cf1ce',
    createdAt: 2023-10-14T10:07:44.386Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-10-14T10:07:44.386Z,
    deletedAt: null,
    users: [
      '888ce1ad-8ee4-4518-977a-78b66275ee9d',
      '529938d1-33fd-4aa1-bd2a-9eb741b5c19f'
    ]
  }
```

Again if i want to find that data already exist in my table or not

```
public async testData(
    firstUserId: string,
    body: AddConversationDto,
  ): {
    const { userId } = body;
     const conversation = await this.chatConversationRepositoryService.findMany({
      users: In[userId],
    });

if (conversation)
  return { message: this.i18nService.t('systemMessage.addConversation') };

await this.chatConversationRepositoryService.save({
  users: [firstUserId, userId],
});

return { message: this.i18nService.t('systemMessage.addConversation') };
```

}
I have tried multiple time to find if already exist but its not working. It is only showing all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that you are using the `simple-array` type. When you fetch the data, TypeORM represents it as an array; however, in the DB, it is not saved as an array. It is a regular string delimited with commas.

[Documentation](https://typeorm.io/entities#simple-array-column-type) states:

> Note you MUST NOT have any comma in values you write.

When you have a list

```
const A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

It will be saved as:

```
"a,b,c"
```

Make sure you are not working with the data that might contain commas or at least clean them up before saving.

In the end, it is a string, which means you need string functions to determine whether it exists or not. `LIKE`, for example.

Another problem I noticed is that you are using the `findMany` function. If you want to determine whether something exists or not, `findMany` is not what you need. This function always returns an array as a response. If there is no match, it will be an empty list, which means your if statement `if (conversation){}` will always be `true` since an empty array needs to be checked by its length, e.g. `if(list.length > 0){}`

Long story short, if the goal is to find only one match, then use `findOne` instead. It will give either the record or a `null` value, unlike `findMany`.

However, in your case, you can leverage using the `exists` method as follows:

```js
const conversation = await this.chatConversationRepositoryService.exist({
  where: {
    users: Like(`%${userId}%`)
  }
});
```

Which will return a boolean value.

P.S.

Make sure you format your code properly when posting here and eliminate all unrelated stuff. This way you increase your chances of getting help on this platform.